# Suppose that a function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, where $a,b,c$ are real constants, satisfy the relation..

Tags: functions, derivatives, quadratics

> Suppose that a function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, where $a,b,c$ are real constants, satisfy the relation
>   $$-1\leq f(x)\leq 1 $$ for all $-1\leq x\leq 1$, then the maximum value of $f'(x)$ is

I think the maximum value of $f'$ is to be found within the limits. I do not have any idea how to do it. I tried analyzing with the help of the graph, the part of the curve must be well inside the square with vertices $(1,1);(-1,1);(-1,-1),(1,-1)$. But I failed. The answer is an integer between 0 and 9. Please give an elegant solution.

Comment: **Hint:**

Since $f'(x)=2ax+b$ its maximum is reached at $x=1$ if $a>0$ or at $x=-1$ if $a<0$.

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos: Yes I know that but I could not use the given conditions to get the correct answer. The answer is an integer between 0 and 9. Could you post a complete solution for this question?

Comment: It is impossible to get an integer answer if $a,b,c$ are, as you write, real. Are you sure that they are not integers?